# Make all but 3 fields read only

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a code to mark fields on my pdf as read only.  I would like 3 of the fields to remain active if they are empty.  How do I adjust the code to exclude 3 fields if they are empty?

```
var currentPageNum = event.target.page;

 for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++){
  var currentField = this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i));

  if (GetFirstFieldPage(currentField) <= currentPageNum){
 currentField.readonly = true;
 currentField.display = display.visible;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use an array to store the names of the three fields that should remain active even if they are empty

```
var currentPageNum = event.target.page;
var activeFields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']; // Names of the fields that should remain active if empty

for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {
  var currentField = this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i));

  if (GetFirstFieldPage(currentField) <= currentPageNum) {
    var fieldValue = currentField.value;
    var isEmptyField = fieldValue === null || fieldValue.trim() === '';

    // Check if the field should remain active if it's empty
    if (activeFields.includes(currentField.name) && isEmptyField) {
      currentField.readonly = false;
      currentField.display = display.visible;
    } else {
      currentField.readonly = true;
      currentField.display = display.visible;
    }
  }
}
```